# why + sign is the exception in javascript?

Tags: javascript, implicit-conversion, dynamic-typing

i did this

```
> 5 + 2 // 7, this is correct 

> 5 - 2 // 3 , obviously 

> 5 - "2" // 3 , ohh, that's awesome 

> 5 % "2" // 1 , :)

> 5 / "2" // 2.5,looks like 2 is automatically converted to integer.Perfect!

> 5 + "2" // "52" Really?
```

Certainty, something extra is going on with plus sign. What's that and why ?

Comment: It converts it to a string there is no subtraction in the strings, so it changes it to numbers.

Comment: `+` is concateniation operator as well.

Comment: it binds strings as well. Like in php you use a dot, in javascript you use +

Comment: The implicit conversion when operating on strings and others is one of the bigger gotchas with JavaScript; what you observe there is (unfortunately) backed by the language standard and as such considered a “feature”.

Comment: try this  `5 + +"2"` and ZOMG !

Comment: And, surprisingly, `+"2"` yields the number 2 (ie not a string).

Comment: As @mpm points out `5 + +"2"` will coerce the string `"2"` into the number `2` so it works as expected, but it could easily be misread as `5 ++2`, which is a syntax error and would mislead one as to the intent of the code because it looks like the increment operator `++`. If using a [unary `+`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#-_.28Unary_Plus.29) in this sort of context it would be clearer if parenthesis were included `5 + (+"2")`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As per the [ECMA 5.1 Standard Specification for Binary + operator](http://es5.github.io/#x11.6.1),

> ```
> 7. If Type(lprim) is String or Type(rprim) is String, then
>       Return the String that is the result of concatenating ToString(lprim)
>       followed by ToString(rprim)
> ```

So, if either of the operands are of type String, then the standard mandates the implementations to convert both the operands to string type and concatenate them.

**Note:** But the [unary + operator](http://es5.github.io/#x11.4.6) behaves differently with strings. It converts the strings to numbers.

> ```
> 1. Let expr be the result of evaluating UnaryExpression.
> 2. Return ToNumber(GetValue(expr)).
> ```

Comment: This is perfectly true, but it doesn't really get to the heart of the philosophical aspects of ***why***.

Comment: @Pointy Sorry, I searched the internet and couldn't find in the first three pages of Google. Could you please share the answer for the why part?

Comment: @Pointy I don't know if there is a specific known philosophical reason. To find that out you would have learn more about the [history of JavaScript](https://www.w3.org/community/webed/wiki/A_Short_History_of_JavaScript). You would need to figure out what version of ECMAScript was made to perform this behavior. Then you would need to ask the person who made it that way. The first version of what came to be known as JavaScript was initially created in 10 days by Brendan Eich. It might have been done early on. You might need to find out what Brendan Eich was thinking at the time.

Comment: Perhaps they ran out of operators and decided to make the addition operator concatenate also as a shortcut. Maybe they got inspiration from another language or another program for that.

Comment: @Pointy There is simply no answer to *why*. JavaScript was designed in a hurry, and then implemented *exactly* in another hurry without looking at whether the language specification was any good or not. It’s simply a decision that wasn’t thought through, which we now have to deal with.

Comment: Sure, I guess I was half-joking :)  These responses do a wonderful job of exploring this deep question of human existence :)  Personally I understand (and like) the use of `+` for string concatenation, and once you've made that decision for a dynamically-typed language you end up with some sort of weirdness inevitably, I think.

Comment: @Pointy I really thought you knew the why part. I was just curious to know :)

Comment: @thefourtheye yes I just extended the comment - languages that use plain whitespace for string concatenation, or other unfamiliar operators, I find confusing and/or plagued by their own problems.

Comment: @Pointy Oh Thanks :) Back then, were there any languages which did that?

Comment: Well `awk` uses spaces for concatenation. Erlang and Haskell use `++` (which of course looks bizarre coming from the C/Java world), PHP (I think) and Perl (?) use `.`, right? That'd be pretty nuts. I'm sure there are others.

Answer (score 1):

`+` is used for concatenation in the case of strings.  It is only used for addition in the case of numbers.

For all the other operators you list, they do not have this dual purpose and the string `"2"` is cast to a number.

Answer (score 0):

Of these operations, the `+` sign is the only symbol that does an operation on numbers and a different operation on strings. All the other symbols only operate on numbers, so type-inference is much simpler.

That said, if `+` is a *unary* operator, then [it converts the argument to a number](http://es5.github.io/#x11.4.6).

Answer (score 0):

> 5 + "2" // "52" Really?

**YES**

5 as A number
"2" as a text

So In Javascript + CONTACTING TWO values

> 5 + "2" to become 7 you need to use parseFloat or parseInt
>
> 5 + parseInt("2") = 7

Comment: Always use a radix when using [`parseInt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt)! Depending on the environment the code runs in not doing so can cause [unexpected results](http://www.michaelgaigg.com/blog/2008/10/07/the-importance-of-the-javascript-parseint-radix/).