# Which javascript function can be used to covert an array of characters into a number?

Tags: javascript, math

There are a few Javascript functions available to convert anything into its equivalent number. `Number()` operates on an `Object`, `valueOf()`, `parseFloat`, `parseInt()` are also available.

I have an array which stores numbers 0-9 and decimal point, the elements of the array taken together represents a number. What is the best way to convert this array into a number, whole or fractional?

EDIT: Apologies if I were not clear before. The array, holding the 0-9 characters and possibly a decimal point, could represent either a whole number(without the decimal obviously) or a fractional number. So please suggest something that works for both cases. Thanks.

Comment: is it like this ````["1",".","9',"1"]````? and should be this :````1.91````?

Comment: I am curious as to why you thought it would be helpful to **not** include an example array?

Comment: yes @JoelRamosMichaliszen

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this

```
var a = [1,2,3,".",2,3];
var num = +a.join("");
```

Comment: For those who aren't aware what the `+` does to a string as a unary operator - http://stackoverflow.com/a/22573090/1808539

Answer (score 0):

> What is the best way to convert this array into a number, whole or fractional?

Firstly to combine your array elements you should use [Array.join()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join).

You will then have a concatenated variable of your values and decimal. To convert this to a whole number, use `parseInt()`, and to a floating point number use `parseFloat()`. You can use the unary `+` operator (which acts similarly to parseFloat), however in my opinion it is not the best choice semantically here, as you seem to want a specific type of number returned.

Example:

```
var arr = ['1','.','9','1'];
var concat = arr.join();
var whole = parseInt(concat);
var floating = parseFloat(concat);
```

Also, `parseInt` will trim the decimal portion of your number, so if you need rounding you can use:

```
var rounded = Math.round(parseFloat(concat));
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the split property of the string. It splits all the characters into an zero based array.

```
var charSplits = "this is getting split.";

var splitArr = charSplits.split();

Console.log(splitArr);

// this returns i 
Console.log(splitArr[2]);
```